# autoit it possible to use "PixelSearch" and "ControlClick" and "PixelGetColor" on bluestacks

Tags: autoit, bluestacks

**possible to use "PixelSearch" and "ControlClick" and "PixelGetColor" on bluestacks in hind windows**

i want to run bot in bluestacks  and hind windows but PixelSearch can only use on Windows

i want to use PixelSearch to find colour if true to click on other point and working in hind windows

```css
Local $hwnd, $Cor
$hwnd = WinGetHandle("WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.33c0d9d")
While 1
$Cor = PixelSearch(460, 271, 511, 323, 0x9D6F47,$hwnd )
If Not @error Then
 ControlClick ( "BlueStacks App Player","","", "left" ,  1 , 477, 277 )
 sleep(200)
EndIf

$Cor = PixelSearch( 546, 212, 598, 267, 0x431567,$hwnd )
If Not @error Then
 ControlClick ( "BlueStacks App Player","","", "left" ,  1 , 608, 512 )
 sleep(200)
EndIf
WEnd
```

i try this code it works when bluestacks on fornt but i move screen or hind bluestacks is not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't catch a pixel on an hidden windows. What you can make it's make it appear quickly (
the time to make a capture) an then search forthe pixel in memory.

That's a very quick process. Take a look at this :

http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/126430-advanced-pixel-search-library/